# Python Function Reference

Tags: python, macos, documentation, reference, widget

There're tons of apps/widgets for PHP function reference and even for Ruby but I'm shocked to find there is nothing available for a popular language like Python (besides the official online documentation ofcourse).

Is there really not a single handy reference widget/app available for Python? I have 'Pocket Reference' book, but a dashboard widget would be so handy!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "reference widget/app", but if you're on Windows there is a handy .chm help file in Python's Doc directory, if that's what you're looking for. It's just a local copy of the online reference.

Comment: No, I'm on Mac. By widget I mean dashboard widget, but app I mean a regular app that allows searching function names and documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python libraries have (or should have) built in documentation through docstrings. Also, python code is (mostly) very readable, and reading the source (.py or even .c) is actually the preferred way for many developers to get the information they're looking for, especially since some corner cases may not even be documented.

I've caught myself looking through the source now and then, as if it's a natural step in looking up functionality, either because I'm curious how they solve the problem, or because I reckon it's faster than googling obscure problems and reading SO questions.

Answer (score 0):

So it's (often) not very pretty at all, but it's possible that the pydoc command line tool, or pydoc in webserver mode, could help you here. [Here's an article on pydoc to help you get started](http://www.oreillynet.com/mac/blog/2005/10/programming_is_just_easier_wit.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. The interactive interpreter is a fantastic reference tool. `dir(<identifier)` lists all the attributes of a module, class, or function `help(<identifier>)` gives you help about same.
2. `pydoc` at the command line is another great tool. It does for Python what `man` gives you for commands, plus it even includes a web server you can start up to see the documentation in your browser.

Answer (score -1):

I develop on Mac OS.

I have all the Python documentation directly available through a desktop app.

The app is called Safari.  I bookmark http://docs.python.org/index.html

It's available as a desktop app.

Comment: Can't you ever refrain from being sarcastic? Sarcasm is the lowest form of wit, didn't you know? I respect you, your rep and your programming abilities but please stop treating others as if they have no brains. I specified in my description "besides official documentation" so your answer is not relevant. I need something similar to this: http://www.artissoftware.com/phpfi/ or http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/developer/phpfunctionreference.html

Comment: Consider this for just a fleeting second.  There's a small possibility that your question was hard to understand.

Comment: Also, consider this: "but I'm shocked to find there is nothing available"  It's not part of the question.  It's (a) a value judgement and (b) negative.   If you could find a way to write without value judgements and negativity, it would be easier to parse your questions properly.  The negative value judgements are a stumbling block.  They're a  red flag.  They're a writing style that occludes your meaning.  They don't add any value to the question.

Comment: Python indeed has "nothing" available compared to PHP documentation where you find function references with multiple examples and usage scenarios. The built-in help and dir functions or the online manual with single-line descriptions are not *very* helpful, especially for an *absolute beginner* like me. I understand that you've spent years programming and questions like these only frustrates you more and makes you wonder "what is so difficult about it" but everything *is* difficult till you *get it*, and I'm not there yet. :)

Comment: @Nimbuz: I'm not commenting in your level of experience.  I'm commenting on your writing style.  This question is prefaced by (a) a value judgement, and (b) negativity.  These do not reflect my experience or yours.  The way you wrote your question obscures what  you're really looking for.   Please avoid (a) value judgements and (b) negative comments if you want your question to get more clear and to-the-point answers.